# Python Pandas Dataframe: Everytime I use dataframe.reindex() all of my data in the dataframe gets deleted however index is correct

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So my code works like this:

I take 2 dataframes(df1, df2) and make them the same size through some sorting by columns:

```
# sort the values in both dataframes by Part Number and Operation so we can reindex them
df1Query = df1Query.sort_values(by=['Part Number', 'Operation'])
df2Query = df2Query.sort_values(by=['Part Number', 'Operation'])
```

Then I use:

```
newIndex = df1.index.tolist()
```

To get a list of the indexes, now I want to change df2 to have the same indexes, so I do:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(newIndex)
```

However, when I do this, all of my data in df2 gets deleted. The only thing that remains is the new index. Why is this? In my Python Interactive Window in VS Code, both df1 and df2 are listed as type dataframe. Something weird I see though is count for df1 is (35, 44) but it only shows df2 as (35). I can't think of why this is happening.

If I declare them as different variables for the second dataframe, like in my Python Interactive Window I view df2Query and df2(after reindex), the only loc that has run is the reindexing but df2Query is still 100% correct and df2 has the data disappear.

Every combination of reindexing I have tried has resulted in a blank dataframe so far. Other things I have tried...

```
df2 = df2.reindex_like(df1)

or 

newIndex = df1.index.tolist()
df2 = df2.set_index(index) #just to see if the index column somehow isnt working right but it seems like it is
```

*EDIT* Sample Data, first is df2, its a smaller dataframe, shape(35,10). Both df1 and df2 look very similar, just df1 has many more columns:

```
{'Part Number': {41: 'ME0000272', 42: 'ME0000272', 43: 'ME0000272', 44: 'ME0000272', 45: 'ME0000272', 46: 'ME0000272', 47: 'ME0000272', 48: 'ME0000272', 49: 'ME0000272', 50: 'ME0000272', 51: 'ME0000273', 52: 'ME0000273', 53: 'ME0000273', 54: 'ME0000273', 55: 'ME0000273', 56: 'ME0000273', 57: 'ME0000273', 58: 'ME0000273', 59: 'ME0000273', 60: 'ME0000273', 61: 'ME0000273', 62: 'ME0000273', 63: 'ME0000273', 74: 'ME0000274', 75: 'ME0000274', 76: 'ME0000274', 77: 'ME0000274', 78: 'ME0000274', 79: 'ME0000274', 80: 'ME0000274', 81: 'ME0000274', 82: 'ME0000274', 83: 'ME0000274', 84: 'ME0000274', 85: 'ME0000274'}, 'Planning Revision': {41: '001B.000', 42: '001B.000', 43: '001B.000', 44: '001B.000', 45: '001B.000', 46: '001B.000', 47: '001B.000', 48: '001B.000', 49: '001B.000', 50: '001B.000', 51: '001A.000', 52: '001A.000', 53: '001A.000', 54: '001A.000', 55: '001A.000', 56: '001A.000', 57: '001A.000', 58: '001A.000', 59: '001A.000', 60: '001A.000', 61: '001A.000', 62: '001A.000', 63: '001A.000', 74: '001A.000', 75: '001A.000', 76: '001A.000', 77: '001A.000', 78: '001A.000', 79: '001A.000', 80: '001A.000', 81: '001A.000', 82: '001A.000', 83: '001A.000', 84: '001A.000', 85: '001A.000'}, 'Operation': {41: '0100-00-0', 42: '0200-00-0', 43: '0300-00-0', 44: '0400-00-0', 45: '0500-00-0', 46: '0600-00-0', 47: '0700-00-0', 48: '0800-00-0', 49: '0900-00-0', 50: '1000-00-0', 51: '0100-00-0', 52: '0200-00-0', 53: '0300-00-0', 54: '0350-00-0', 55: '0400-00-0', 56: '0500-00-0', 57: '0600-00-0', 58: '0700-00-0', 59: '0800-00-0', 60: '0900-00-0', 61: '1000-00-0', 62: '1100-00-0', 63: '1200-00-0', 74: '0100-00-0', 75: '0200-00-0', 76: '0300-00-0', 77: '0400-00-0', 78: '0500-00-0', 79: '0600-00-0', 80: '0700-00-0', 81: '0800-00-0', 82: '0900-00-0', 83: '1000-00-0', 84: '1100-00-0', 85: '1200-00-0'}, 'Part Description': {41: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 42: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 43: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 44: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 45: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 46: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 47: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 48: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 49: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 50: 'SEAL, LABYRINTH-COMB AFT', 51: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 52: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 53: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 54: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 55: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 56: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 57: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 58: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 59: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 60: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 61: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 62: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 63: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 74: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 75: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 76: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 77: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 78: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 79: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 80: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 81: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 82: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 83: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 84: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER', 85: 'SEAL ASSY, REAR, FUEL SLINGER'}, 'Operation Description': {41: 'ISSUE MATERIAL', 42: 'CLEAN PARTS', 43: 'PROG #8-27: P1270 OR 1272 (PRECIP HARDEN INCO718 @ 1325/480 MIN)', 44: 'MACHINE - SIDE 1', 45: 'MACHINE - SIDE 2', 46: 'DEBURR', 47: 'CLEAN PARTS', 48: 'IDENTIFY', 49: 'FINAL INSPECTION', 50: 'STORE', 51: 'ISSUE', 52: 'ROUGH MACHINE I.D.', 53: 'ROUGH MACHINE O.D.', 54: 'DEBURR', 55: 'CLEAN PARTS', 56: 'PROG #8-27: P1270 OR 1272 (PRECIP HARDEN INCO 718 @ 1325 / 480 MIN)', 57: 'FINISH MACHINE ID', 58: 'FINISH MACHINE OD', 59: 'DEBURR', 60: 'CLEAN PARTS', 61: 'IDENTIFY', 62: 'FINAL INSPECTION', 63: 'STORE', 74: 'ISSUE', 75: 'ROUGH MACHINE ID', 76: 'ROUGH MACHINE OD', 77: 'CLEAN PARTS', 78: 'PROG #8-27: P1270 OR 1272 (PRECIP HARDEN INCO 718 @ 1325 / 480 MIN)', 79: 'FINISH MACHINE ID', 80: 'FINISH MACHINE OD', 81: 'DEBURR', 82: 'CLEAN PARTS', 83: 'IDENTIFY', 84: 'FINAL INSPECTION', 85: 'STORE'}, 'Planning Status': {41: 'W4_RELEASED', 42: 'W4_RELEASED', 43: 'W4_RELEASED', 44: 'W4_RELEASED', 45: 'W4_RELEASED', 46: 'W4_RELEASED', 47: 'W4_RELEASED', 48: 'W4_RELEASED', 49: 'W4_RELEASED', 50: 'W4_RELEASED', 51: 'W4_RELEASED', 52: 'W4_RELEASED', 53: 'W4_RELEASED', 54: 'W4_RELEASED', 55: 'W4_RELEASED', 56: 'W4_RELEASED', 57: 'W4_RELEASED', 58: 'W4_RELEASED', 59: 'W4_RELEASED', 60: 'W4_RELEASED', 61: 'W4_RELEASED', 62: 'W4_RELEASED', 63: 'W4_RELEASED', 74: 'W4_RELEASED', 75: 'W4_RELEASED', 76: 'W4_RELEASED', 77: 'W4_RELEASED', 78: 'W4_RELEASED', 79: 'W4_RELEASED', 80: 'W4_RELEASED', 81: 'W4_RELEASED', 82: 'W4_RELEASED', 83: 'W4_RELEASED', 84: 'W4_RELEASED', 85: 'W4_RELEASED'}, 'Resopnsible Cell': {41: 'H01', 42: 'H01', 43: 'H01', 44: 'H01', 45: 'H01', 46: 'H01', 47: 'H01', 48: 'H01', 49: 'H01', 50: 'H01', 51: 'H44', 52: 'H44', 53: 'H44', 54: 'H44', 55: 'H44', 56: 'H44', 57: 'H44', 58: 'H44', 59: 'H44', 60: 'H44', 61: 'H44', 62: 'H44', 63: 'H44', 74: 'H44', 75: 'H44', 76: 'H44', 77: 'H44', 78: 'H44', 79: 'H44', 80: 'H44', 81: 'H44', 82: 'H44', 83: 'H44', 84: 'H44', 85: 'H44'}, 'Work Center': {41: '500SSA', 42: '500CPW', 43: '534HFI', 44: '500LNP', 45: '500LNP', 46: '500YDC', 47: '500CPW', 48: '500YIC', 49: '500QII', 50: '500SSA', 51: '500SSA', 52: '500LNP', 53: '500LNP', 54: '500YDC', 55: '500CPW', 56: '534HFI', 57: '500LNP', 58: '500LNP', 59: '500YDC', 60: '500CPW', 61: '500YIC', 62: '500QII', 63: '500SSA', 74: '500SSA', 75: '500LNP', 76: '500LNP', 77: '500CPW', 78: '534HFI', 79: '500LNP', 80: '500LNP', 81: '500YDC', 82: '500CPW', 83: '500YIC', 84: '500QII', 85: '500SSA'}, 'Work Center Description': {41: 'HQ Cell Stores', 42: 'PARTS WASHER', 43: 'VACUUM FURNACE', 44: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 45: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 46: 'HAND DEBURR', 47: 'PARTS WASHER', 48: 'HAND IDENTIFY', 49: 'FINAL INSPECTION - HQ', 50: 'HQ Cell Stores', 51: 'HQ Cell Stores', 52: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 53: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 54: 'HAND DEBURR', 55: 'PARTS WASHER', 56: 'VACUUM FURNACE', 57: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 58: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 59: 'HAND DEBURR', 60: 'PARTS WASHER', 61: 'HAND IDENTIFY', 62: 'FINAL INSPECTION - HQ', 63: 'HQ Cell Stores', 74: 'HQ Cell Stores', 75: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 76: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 77: 'PARTS WASHER', 78: 'VACUUM FURNACE', 79: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 80: 'PUMA LATHE GT3100M', 81: 'HAND DEBURR', 82: 'PARTS WASHER', 83: 'HAND IDENTIFY', 84: 'FINAL INSPECTION - HQ', 85: 'HQ Cell Stores'}, 'Engine / Project': {41: None, 42: None, 43: None, 44: None, 45: None, 46: None, 47: None, 48: None, 49: None, 50: None, 51: None, 52: None, 53: None, 54: None, 55: None, 56: None, 57: None, 58: None, 59: None, 60: None, 61: None, 62: None, 63: None, 74: None, 75: None, 76: None, 77: None, 78: None, 79: None, 80: None, 81: None, 82: None, 83: None, 84: None, 85: None}}
```

df1 is too large to fit, but its shape is (35,44) and contains these column headers (10 of the headers are the exact same as df2's):

```
Index(['Part Number', 'Operation', 'Part Description', 'Engine / Project',
       'Resopnsible Cell', 'Lead', 'Support', 'Component Status',
       'Planning Revision', 'Priority', 'ECD / Status', 'Planning Status',
       'Tool Design', 'Tool Available', 'NC Program Status', 'Gage Status',
       'Gage Available', 'Perishable Tool Status', 'CMM Fixture Design',
       'CMM Fixture Available', 'CMM Program Status', 'CMM Programmer',
       'Work Center', 'Work Center Type', 'Work Center Description',
       'Operation Description', 'Date On Machine', 'FAIR', 'Notes',
       'On Machine?', 'Quantity On Hand', 'Earliest MRP/HRP Date',
       'Open Order Quantity', 'Behind', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
       'Aug', 'Total To Aug', 'Demand To 3/26/2023', 'Demand To 5/6/2022',
       'O/P Quote Received'],
      dtype='object')
```

The ideal output would be:

```
df1
index data
1000  ABC
1001  DEF
1002  GHI
1003  JKL

df2
index data
0     MNO
1     PQR
2     STU
3     VWX

and then...
df2.'change index'() = 
index data
1000  MNO
1001  PQR
1002  STU
1003  VWX
```

Comment: Could you share sample data for `df1` and `df2` that reproduces the issue? The output of `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()` should suffice

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I tried to update the best I could, df1 is a lot bigger, but I hope I provided enough info. Like each have the same number of rows, just df1 has about 34 more columns of data. df2 shares all of its headers with df1, because once I reindex df2 I am going to merge them to update the data in df1 with the data in df2.